# Jython random string generation

Tags: java, python, string, random, jython

So, I need to make a method that would return a random string based on given length in jython. It would be easy if I could implement python random, but on I could not find a way to do that, since in every random example I found that java random class is used instead of python.
Here is the code bit:

```
  def getrstr (self, length):
    from java.util import Random
    import string
    chars = string.letter + string.digits
    str = ''
    for i in range(1, (length+1)):
      ind = random.nextInt(62) #there should be 62 charicters in chars string
      c = #this is the part where i should get radom char from string using ind
      str = str + c
    return str
```

I am trying to make a string based on string containing all chars I need. I just can't seam to find a way to access char in string by index, like I would in C#.

Any ideas how to do that or maybe even import python random class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c = chars.charAt(ind);
```

[JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) guide the way.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case, how do I differentiate between python and java provided classes? I did import java.lang.String class and made that char string as java string object, but it still considers it a python object, there for cant call the charAt method. Any ideas?

Comment: If it's still a python object, why can't you access it with the [] notation? I haven't worked with Jython for a while, but IIRC that should still be working. Otherwise, create a Java object with `charsJava = java.lang.String(chars)` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for me with Jython:

```
def getrstr(self, length):
    import random, string
    seq = string.letters + string.digits
    randomstr = []
    for i in xrange(length):
        randomstr.append(random.choice(seq))
    return ''.join(randomstr)
```

Notice that I'm using Jython's `random` module, not Java's `Random` class. An even shorter version, using list comprehensions with module-level imports (as per pep-8):

```
import random, string

def getrstr(self, length):
    seq = string.letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(seq) for _ in xrange(length))
```

Comment: [pep-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends module-level imports.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian edited my answer according to your suggestion. I agree, but thought it was OK for the OP since in his question the imports are inside the method.